# GET data after POST function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have POST function and it's post data to sharepoint list after that I need to refresh the page to show the data. I tried to run GET function put it Didn't Print the data

[image]

after clicking on arrow 1 POST function start and send the data to sharepoint list
after the data should be visible here with the 3 but it didn't show I need to refresh the page to show the data

-I got an idea that to print temporary UseState to show the data but I dont know how to do it

here is my latest code

```html
function Feed(props) { 
 const [data,setdata] = useState(props)

 
  return (
    <div>
      {data.data.map((item) => {
       var spFormated = Moment(item.fields.Date).format('MM/DD/YYYY')
        if (formated == spFormated ) {
          if(item.fields.Hours<=2){
            return(
            <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
              <div className="taskcolorback-div" />
              <button className="taskcolor-button" />
              <input className="tasktext-b" defaultValue={Moment(item.fields.Date).format('MM/DD/YYYY')}></input>
              <button className="taskwhite-button" />
              <b className="timeinline">{item.fields.Hours}Hr</b>
              <img className="vector-icon" alt="" src="icons8-chevron-right-64.png" />
            </React.Fragment>)
          }
         else if(item.fields.Hours==3){
            return( 
            <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
              <div className="taskcolorback-div3" />
              <button className="taskcolor-button3" />
              <input className="tasktext-b3" defaultValue={Moment(item.fields.Date).format('MM/DD/YYYY')}></input>
              <button className="taskwhite-button3" />
              <b className="timeinline3">{item.fields.Hours}Hr</b>
              <img className="vector-icon3" alt="" src="icons8-chevron-right-64.png" />
            </React.Fragment>)
          }
          else if(item.fields.Hours==4){
            return(
            <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
              <div className="taskcolorback-div4" />
              <button className="taskcolor-button4" />
              <input className="tasktext-b4" defaultValue={Moment(item.fields.Date).format('MM/DD/YYYY')}></input>
              <button className="taskwhite-button4" />
              <b className="timeinline4">{item.fields.Hours}Hr</b>
              <img className="vector-icon4" alt="" src="icons8-chevron-right-64.png" />
            </React.Fragment>)
          }
          else if(item.fields.Hours>=5){
            return(             
            <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
              <div className="taskcolorback-div5" />
              <button className="taskcolor-button5" />
              <input className="tasktext-b5" defaultValue={Moment(item.fields.Date).format('MM/DD/YYYY')}></input>
              <button className="taskwhite-button5" />
              <b className="timeinline5">{item.fields.Hours}Hr</b>
              <img className="vector-icon5" alt="" src="icons8-chevron-right-64.png" />
            </React.Fragment>)
          }
          return(
          <> 
         <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
          <div className="taskcolorback-div" />
          <button className="taskcolor-button" />
          <input className="tasktext-b" defaultValue={Moment(item.fields.Date).format('MM/DD/YYYY')}></input>
          <button className="taskwhite-button" />
          <b className="timeinline">{item.fields.Hours}Hr</b>
          <img className="vector-icon" alt="" src="icons8-chevron-right-64.png" />
        </React.Fragment>  
         </>
      )
        }

        // ️ render nothing
        return console.log("null");
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note: The map function will get the data from API

```js
import { graphConfig,graphConfigh } from "./authConfig";

/**
 * Attaches a given access token to a MS Graph API call. Returns information about the user
 * @param accessToken 
 */
export async function callMsGraph(accessToken) {
    const headers = new Headers();
    const bearer = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;

    headers.append("Authorization", bearer);

    const options = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: headers
    };

    return fetch(graphConfig.graphMeEndpoint, options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
}

//-------------------------------
export async function PostData(accessToken) {
    const headers = new Headers();
    const bearer = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;

    headers.append("Authorization", bearer);
    const options = {
        method: "post",
        headers:  {
            'Authorization': bearer,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({fields: {Title: 'TEST',Date: '08/13/2022',Hours:"3"}})
    };

    return fetch(graphConfigh.graphMeEndpointh, options)
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

Comment: Where are you performing a POST or GET at all in this code?

Comment: Show the code for Api call